# Table does not show all lines with ngFor-Angular 11

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular11

I'm trying to create a table to show dates of the week, everyday has his own available appointments, but I don't know why if the array has 9 records, the table shows only 3 and I can see in the image how the table looks truncated:

[image: result]

The HTML code is:

```
<table>
    <colgroup span="6" width="100"></colgroup>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-title" colspan="6">
        {{getMonth() | date: 'MMMM'}} {{getYear()}} / {{'tvo.terminauswahl.week' | translate}} {{date | date:'w'}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" *ngFor="let dayName of headColumns;" >
        <span>{{dayName | translate}}</span>
        <br>
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let dateOftheWeek of datesOfTheWeek">
        {{dateOftheWeek | date:'dd.MM'}}
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let availability of getData()">
      <td>
        <button class="appointments-bt" (click)="onNextStep($event)">
          {{availability.startTime}} - {{availability.endTime}}
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is not enough information - the ngfor loop should be working - so there is most likely a problem here let dateOftheWeek of datesOfTheWeek, try and an add an index let dateOftheWeek of datesOfTheWeek, let i = index;

Comment: Use an async pipe after getData method. `let availability of getData() | async`.

Comment: possible you has an error in console.  (you can see using F12) Angular when an error happens no paint more. check if "getdata()" return an array and all the elements has startTime and endTime -else use safe operator `availability?.startTime` and `availability?.endTime`

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Eliseo you were right in the console I had no errors but in the css I had, the container hat an specific size, I removed that and now is working fine.

Comment: There is no way anyone except you could have answered this question conclusively. These three made educated guesses, but that's all that was possible. I don't think, given the question as written, and the answer, that this is helpful for later visitors.

Comment: Yes, I tried to deleted but it is still there, I have not enough privileges. But how knows maybe somebody will make the same mistake and this would guided to a solution. That is why I answered.

Answer (score 0):

I had errors in the table structure itself and my container had an overflow: hidden.

So I fixed both and the result of the html is:

```
<table>
    <colgroup span="6" [ngStyle]="{'width':'100'}"></colgroup>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-title" colspan="6">
        <button class="week" *ngIf="validPrevWeek()" (click)="prevWeek()"><i name="iconLeft_32" ></i></button>
        {{date | date: 'MMMM'}}
        {{date | date: 'YYYY'}} / {{'tvo.terminauswahl.week' | translate}} {{date | date:'w'}}
        <button class="week" (click)="nextWeek()"><i name="iconRight_32" ></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" *ngFor="let weekData of dayWithTime;let i = index;">
        <span>{{weekData.day | translate}}</span>
        <br>
        <span>{{weekData.date | date:'dd.MM'}}</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td *ngFor="let weekData of dayWithTime; let i = index;" class="dayColumn" [ngClass]="changeBG()">
        <div *ngFor="let availability of weekData.appointments;">
          <div *ngIf="availability.showAppointment else noAvailability" >
            <button class="appointments-bt" (click)="updateDateSelected($event, weekData.date)">
              {{availability.startTime}} - {{availability.endTime}}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```